# Foreach invalid statement for only one case in condition

Tags: php, foreach

I have a form that allows 1 to multiple file uploads. I just noticed that when making multiple file uploads with a submission there is an error.

`Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

For this line:

`foreach ($filename as $indFile) {`

The files upload, but it is effecting other areas in the file due to the error.

What could be wrong that this error is showing up only when multiple files are being uploaded?

```
foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
    foreach($file['name'] as $key => $value) {
        if (!empty($value)) { //empty string
            if($file['error'][$key] != 4) { //error code is not #4
                $fu = new fileUpload();
                $filename = $fu->upload();
                $out = (count($filename) > 1 ? 'Multiple files were' : 'A file was'). '  uploaded. You can download ' . (count($filename) > 1 ? 'them' : 'the file'). ' from:</ul>';
                foreach ($filename as $indFile) {
                    $out .= "<li><a href='uploads/{$indFile}'>{$indFile}</a></li>";
                }
                $out .= '</ul>';
                $template = str_replace("{filename}", $out, $template);

                //echo "name is NOT empty AND error is NOT 4";
            } else { //error code IS #4
                //echo "error code is 4";
            }
        } else {
            //echo "name is empty!";
            $template = str_replace("{filename}", '', $template);
        }
    }
}
clearstatcache();
```

Comment: I suggest you `var_export($filename)` before that `foreach` loop, that should tell you.

Comment: Your problem is in the `fileUpload` class. `$fu->upload()` is returning something that is not iterable.

Comment: @Siguza `$filename` is not defined before the loop, so it is throwing an undefined errror when trying to `var_export`.

Comment: @Paul but you have `$filename = $fu->upload();` right there. Put it between that statement and the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @Siguza Sorry, I completely missed your last comment. I just did as you suggested. This outputs... `array (
  0 => 'aboveFold.PNG',
  1 => 'afterglow.png',
)0<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in`

Comment: @Paul Okay, see that `0` after the closing parentheses? Pretty sure that's from the second iteration of one of the outer loops. From the looks of it, `$fu->upload();` processes all uploaded files at once, and when you call it a second time, it returns zero.

Comment: @Siguza Ahh ok. Any suggestions on what I should do then?